# Issue With Maven War Plugin - class fiels are not getting generated

Tags: java, maven

I am having a pom file like below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.simple.websocket</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-simple-websocket</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-simple-websocket Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
    <finalName>my-simple-websocket</finalName>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I ran mvn clean install, its creating the war file but instead of the class file inside WEB_INF/classes its the java files coming there . Any idea how to fix the problem ?

Comment: Can you just check with `mvn compile war:exploded` ?

Comment: It sounds like your source files are in the wrong place. Please post your project directory layout.